# Applying SignalR to update gridview

Tags: javascript, webforms, signalr

So  when using signalR. I followed this example and got it working on a test web form, where in I open 2 tabs of the same page and tested it out:

[SignalR Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Now I tried to modify it a little bit and tried to have 1 page as a sender and another as a receiver,

Page with Button to send message:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var msg = $.connection.myHub1;   //change MyHub1.cs should be in camel myHub
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            msg.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // $("[id*=btnRefresh]").click();
            };
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                function RefreshData() {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    msg.server.send('admin', 'Refresh Grid');


                };
            });
        });
    </script>

  protected void btnSendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SigalRFunction", "RefreshData()", true);
    }
```

Page with gridview:

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRefresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" Style="display: none" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var msg = $.connection.myHub1;   //change MyHub1.cs should be in camel myHub
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            msg.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {

                $("[id=btnRefresh]").click();
                

            };
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                function RefreshData() {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    //msg.server.send('admin', 'Refresh Grid');


                };
            });
        });
    </script>
 protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdview.DataSource = grdviewData();
        grdview.DataBind();
    }
```

My idea was every time a message is received, the grid view/page should should automatically refresh. The grdviewDatasource and Databind works  i.e placed it in pageload.Sadly nothing happens.

```
script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
```

Comment: Why did you use button to update the gridview? What is the essence of the signalR when the execution of the connection on the hub is successful? We all know that the button will always trigger onSubmit (PostBack)  without using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying that you can invoke the hub's method either from client-side or code-behind code. Since it is not clear which way you want I'll cover both.

Your hub, `MyHub1` should define the `Send` method, which you are going to invoke when the button is clicked:

**MyHub1.cs**

```
public class MyHub1 : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub1>();

        hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Note that the `Send` method calls the `broadcastMessage` javascript function (to notify clients), which you should define in the *Receiver*. You should add any code necessary to refresh your grid inside that function.

**Receiver.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var msg = $.connection.myHub1;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        msg.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            console.log(name + ", " + message);
            // do whatever you have to do to refresh the grid
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        });

    });
</script>
```

The *Sender* contains the two buttons: `btnSendMsg` will invoke the hub's `Send` method from code-behind; `btnSendMsg2` will perform the same invocation from javascript. You can pick either depending on your needs.

**Sender.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSendMsg" runat="server" Text="Server-Side" OnClick="btnSendMsg_Click" />
        <input type="button" id="btnSendMsg2" value="Client-Side" />
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var msg = $.connection.myHub1;  

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#btnSendMsg2').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                msg.server.send('admin', 'Refresh Grid');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Sender.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnSendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myHub1 = new MyHub1();

    myHub1.Send("admin", "Refresh Grid");
}
```

Last but not least, make sure both the sender and the receiver pages reference the necessary jQuery and SignalR scripts and the autogenerated SignalR hub script.

Comment: thank you so much!!! I tried the code behind way and was able to update my gridview everytime I a button was clicked from other page :D